# Swift iOS 16 - Disable sidebar in photo picker

Tags: ios, swift, ipad, uikit, ios16

Apple added a new feature for iOS 16 and mainly for the iPad. In PhotoPicker if your screen is large enough it will display a sidebar:
iOS 16 new way:
[image: new way]

is there a way to return it back how it was originally without the sidebar no matter the size of a screen?
iOS 15- old way:
[image: old way]

Thank you for your help.